# Как авторизироваться с помощью curl, если пароль содержит двоеточия, одинарные и двойные кавычки?

Tags: curl, авторизация

Стандартный вход на сайт с авторизацией выглядит так:

```
curl -u username:password site.ru
```

Если подставить пароль

```
123:'"456
```

в команду, то bash ищет закрытие одинарной кавычки, а curl, возможно, нестандартно будет вести себя из-за двоеточия.

Comment: В чем проблема то? Где код, где что? Вот так берете и авторизовываетесь.

Comment: Точно, спасибо!

    curl -u username:123\:\'\"456 site.ru

Comment: И вопрос вообще-то должен звучать "как сэкранировать кавычки в bash", к curl не имеет ровно никакого отношения.

Comment: @VladD ну может человек просто не знал об этом :-)

Comment: @lampa: добавьте как ответ, а?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

попробуйте подставить слеши?

```
curl -u "123:'\"456" site.ru
```

т.е. экранируйте кавычки